# Where to find icons from VS Code autocompletion list

Tags: visual-studio-code

**VS Code** has many icons for auto completion list: for class/function/snippet/module/inclide/type/etc items. I want to see all these icons and use them in my open source project. Where to find them?

Answer (score 1):

You can download from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/resources)

Or checkout VSC and get all icons.

Comment: There I've found icons for window background and for file types; no icons for autocompletion found.